# Using lots of sound in a AS3 project

Tags: flash, audio

I have around 400 sounds in my flash file.

Is there anyway to go about using them with having to instantiate them all.I will be storing them in an array.

```
var sound1:Sound = snd1;
var soundN:Sound = sndn;

var mySounds:Array =[sound1,soundN....];
```

I already have linkages in the library as sound1,soundN,etc

Answer (score 1):

I usually put the sounds in a separate SWF and then use a JSFL script I have written to generate an array of the sounds id in the SWF. Then I loop through the array and instantiate the sounds using the id in the array. I recommend writing a SoundManager class to do these kind of things for you. I use my JSFL to generate a Type class to easier get access of the sound id.

Something like this:

```
SoundManager.getInstance().addSounds(soundArray);
SoundManager.getInstance().playSound(SoundList.PLAYER_DIE);
```